# How to permanently delete photos [with photo name] from telegram using API in ASP.NET C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, telegram, webapi

I am looking to delete a photo (`test.png`) permanently from telegram, sent by my bot using telegram API and I'm able to deleting the photo (message) using [deleteMessage](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#deletemessage) so if I use the same photo with the same name (photo ex: `test.png`) and modifying that photo and re-sending to telegram channel using API, photo is sending but it is not going as I modified photo it is going like initially sent photo (because the photo name{test.png} is already saved in telegram) so is it possible to delete a photo with the name also from telegram using API ?

Please suggest a way to achieve this.

Comment: Hi @Kumar I'm also looking a solution on this hope some one help you on this.

Comment: Have you ask the Telegram support about this? If there is a way, they should know ... but judging from the API docs, I don't see any method to do this ....

Comment: Hi @marc_s thanks for your comment and I raised a ticket to telegram support team but didn't get any reply from them, may be it will take some time.